# Server issue with large file upload?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, plupload, whm

I have a dedicated server Linux WHM/Cpanel that hosts a video streaming website.  I have a form to upload videos and I've been trying to upload larger files but failing?  I've checked error logs and nothing is leading me in the right direction. Below are my php.ini settings

```
upload_max_filesize = 1200M
post_max_size = 1200M
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = -1
max_file_uploads = 20
max_execution_time = 7200
max_input_time = 7200
max_input_vars = 1000
```

I can upload a 100MB file just fine but the movies i have can be up to 1gb.  I'm using Plupload to upload files.  I've tested several small size files and they upload fine.  When I try to upload large movies e.g. 300mb, Plupload returns this error **HTTP Error. Upload URL might be wrong or doesn't exist.** and this is the only clue I have.  Plupload uses chunking to split up large files also.

This only happens with larger files.  It's really a nuisance also, since I have to upload large files all over again to see if my changes are successful or not.

Any ideas?  Why would it work with a smaller size file but not larger? I have no errors to work from.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Error is common when there is something wrong with the files being uploaded. Please check your server info with php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize is the limit of any single file. 
post_max_size is the limit of the entire body of the request,
```

Sometimes the server requires `post_max_size` greater than `upload_max_filesize` I might be wrong but I have to check.

Try debugging the issue removing the chunking first and then later add the chunking part when you remove those HTTP errors.